# Show only user from the same company

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I want ask how it's possible when an user [Type=Chef](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7wcK.png) logs into the website, in the [Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYt9i.png) it only shows the user from his company Foreign key (fk_FirmaID). I don't how process it to only show a specific company.

Here is my code that I have for the moment. When an user is logging in I'm saving his user details in a $_SESSION. Updated the code cause I send the wrong one. Here is my [database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvXUE.png).

```
<?php
session_start();
require('config.php');
include('functions.php');
$sessionType = (!empty($_SESSION['type']))?$_SESSION['type']:null;
$sessionUsername = (!empty($_SESSION['username']))?$_SESSION['username']:null;
$sessionfkfirma = (!empty($_SESSION['fk_FirmaID']))?$_SESSION['fk_FirmaID']:null;
$msg = null;
$stmt = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM benutzer");



if(isset($_POST['modifySubmit'])) {
  $newname = $_POST['newname'];
  $userid = $_POST['userid'];
  $stmt = mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE benutzer SET username = '$newname' WHERE id = $userid");
  if($stmt){
    $msg = alert_success("Good Job, Buddy! The record has been updated successfully.");
  }else{
    $msg = alert_error();
  }
}

if(!empty($_GET['delete'])) { //
  $id = $_GET['delete'];
  $stmt = mysqli_query($link, "DELETE FROM benutzer WHERE id = $id");
  if($stmt) {
    $msg = alert_success("Good Job, Buddy! The record has been deleted sucessfully.");
  }else{
    $msg = alert_error();
  }
}


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Panel</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="page-head">
      <center>
      <img src="logo.png" alt="logo" width="170px" height="170px">
    </center><br><br>
      <h1>Admin Panel</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="left">
      <center>
        <a href="welcome.php" class="btn btn-default">Go Back</a>
        <a href="adduser.php" class="btn btn-info">Create user</a>
      </center>
    </div>
    <br>
    <?php echo $msg; if(!empty($_GET['modify'])){ ?>
      <div class="modify-user text-center">
        <div class="row">
          <h4 class="text-center">Modify user</h4>
        </div>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <form method="post" action="" onSubmit="return confirm('Are you sure you want to update this user?')">
                          <input type="hidden" name="userid" value="<?php echo $_GET['modify']; ?>">
                          <input type="text" name="newname" placeholder="Name / Vorname" class="text-center" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['modifySubmit'])){ echo $_POST['newname']; } ?>"><br><br>
                  <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" name="modifySubmit">
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
      </div>
    <?php } ?>
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table">
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Name / Vorname</th>
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>Type</th>
          <th>Firma</th>
          <?php $row = mysqli_fetch_array($stmt);
          if(($sessionType == 'Admin') or ($sessionType == 'Chef')){ ?>
          <th>Modify</th>
          <?php
          if(($sessionType == 'Admin') or ($sessionType === 'Chef')){ ?>
            <th>Delete</th>
          <?php }} ?>
        </tr>
        <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($stmt)){ ?>
          <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['username']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['type']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['fk_FirmaID']; ?></td>
            <?php if(($sessionType == 'Admin') or ($sessionType == 'Chef') and ($sessionType == 'Mitarbeiter' or $sessionUsername != $row['username'])){ ?>
            <td><a href="panel.php?modify=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Modify</a></td>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php if(($sessionType == 'Admin') or ($sessionType == 'Chef')  and ($sessionType == 'Mitarbeiter' or $sessionUsername != $row['username'])){ ?>
              <td><a href="panel.php?delete=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"  onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this user?')">Delete</a></td>
            <?php } ?>
          </tr>
        <?php } ?>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Need a bit of a logic check here! Why run a query and afterwards check the session for logged in users. The logged in check uses Nothing from the query result

Comment: FWIW, including spaces in table/column identifiers is a cataclysmically bad idea

Comment: According to Strawberry's comment: common naming convention for MySQL is using small caps without spaces, always, so It can be `fk_firma_id`, `firma_name`, etc. Don't ask, believe us, you'll thank us later.

Comment: Updated the code send the wrong one

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should alway use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!

Comment: A delete request should definitely not be coming through `$_GET`

Comment: @mickmackusa I used `$_GET` to get the ID of the user in that row. I found no other ways to do it.

Comment: Using `$_GET` invites so much as a webcrawler to programmatically delete all of your records.  Security aside, it is considered best practice to use `$_GET` for reading and `$_POST` for writing.  You need some prepared statements anyhow.  And read about the null coalescing operator.

Comment: I know but the problem is that the logged in user can only see his company and not the others.

Comment: You need to use the ID in the session in a where clause of the query. Presumably the user's record in the database holds the ID of their company. Therefore you can join that to the company table and then join that to the table of the records you want to display. It's hard to be more specific without knowing your database structure.

Comment: Here is my database structure it's in German so you must translate it. https://prnt.sc/10fen9h

Comment: Thanks but no, it's your job to translate the names of the relevant tables and fields for us - if you want our (free) help then don't make people do extra work for the privilege! Also please add those details (the picture and the translation) to the question, rather than hiding it down here in the comments :-)

Comment: Here @ADyson I updated it to English https://prnt.sc/10ff8r9

Comment: Please add it to the question too :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to achieve!

```
$stmt = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM benutzer INNER JOIN firma ON benutzer.fk_FirmaID = firma.FirmaID");
```

You need to use JOIN to connect between both the tables. Here, INNER JOIN returns only those data for whom the records are matching in both the fields. It eliminates the rest of the result.